# Strange exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Hey guys we are trying to make a client-server racing game for our semester project but we have some strange error

```
public void updatePosition(int id, ArrayList<Point2D.Float> positions){
    if(id==1){
        for (int i = 1; i < game.getS().getVehicles().size(); i++)
        {
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).updatePosition(positions.get(i));              
        }

    }else if(id==2){
        game.getS().getVehicles().get(1).updatePosition(positions.get(0));              
        for (int i = 2; i < game.getS().getVehicles().size(); i++)
        {
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).updatePosition(positions.get(i));  
        }
```

this is our code

and the exception is in this exact row:
    game.getS().getVehicles().get(1).updatePosition(positions.get(0));

Comment: And where exactly is the exception? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 4):

References are initialized to null by default.  If you create a collection or array, and fail to initialize references, they'll be null by default.

Comment: so what can we change or where we should search ?

Comment: Make the references not null.  You're assuming that you've got good data in the collection, but the JVM is telling you that you don't.  Check your assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

A `NullPointerException` can occur in many places in this small fragment of code.

Basically, when you have an expression of the kind `a.b().c()`, a `NullPointerException` can be thrown if `a` is `null`, or if `b()` returns `null`.

If you are uncertain that all of the parts of such an expression are not null, you have to perform explicit checking:

```
if (a != null) {
  WhateverObject intermediate = a.b();

  if (intermediate != null) {
    intermediate.c(); 
  }
}
```