# index ot of bounds exception

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
game.getS().getVehicles().get(1).updatePosition(positions.get(0));
```

we are making a client - server racing game and we got this exception in this exact line what can we do or what can we change? here i will show you the all code:

```
package speedrace.client;

import static speedrace.common.Config.*;

import speedrace.common.*;
import speedrace.game.Car;
import speedrace.game.CarGame;
import speedrace.game.Player;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D.Float;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SpeedRaceClientController extends UnicastRemoteObject implements
        RaceObserver, RaceUpdate
{
    private RaceSubject serverGet;
    private RaceUpdate serverSet;
    private SpeedRaceClientView view;

    private int clientID = 0;
    private Player currentPlayer = null;
    private CarGame game = new CarGame();

    public SpeedRaceClientController() throws Exception
    {
        super();
        game.setVisible(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Player getCurrentPlayer() throws RemoteException
    {
        return currentPlayer;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCurrentPlayer(Player currentPlayer) throws RemoteException
    {
        this.currentPlayer = currentPlayer;

    }

    @Override
    public int getClientID()
    {
        return clientID;
    }

    @Override
    public void setClientID(int clientID)
    {
        this.clientID = clientID;
    }

    @Override
    public CarGame getGame()
    {
        return game;
    }

    @Override
    public void setGame(CarGame game)
    {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void begin(SpeedRaceClientView view)
    {
        this.view = view;

        try
        {
            String ip = view.inputIP();
            String URL = "rmi://" + ip + "/" + SERVICE;

            serverSet = (RaceUpdate) Naming.lookup(URL);
            serverGet = (RaceSubject) Naming.lookup(URL);

            serverGet.attach(this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            view.error("Trouble connecting to server");

            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updatePlayerList(Vector<Player> playersList)
            throws RemoteException
    {
        view.showOnlinePlayers(playersList);

    }

    @Override
    public void registerNewPlayer(Player player, int clientID)
            throws RemoteException
    {
        try
        {
            serverSet.registerNewPlayer(player, clientID);
        }
        catch (RemoteException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            view
                    .error("Trouble connecting to server. Please restart the server.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void startGame() throws RemoteException
    {

        try
        {
            serverSet.startGame();

        }

        catch (RemoteException re)
        {
            re.printStackTrace();
            view
                    .error("Trouble connecting to server. Please restart the server.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startTheGame(ArrayList<Point2D.Float> positions,
            Vector<RaceObserver> observers) throws RemoteException
    {

        switch (clientID)
        {
            case 1:
                game.updatePosition(273, 471);
                break;
            case 2:
                game.updatePosition(315, 408);
                break;
            case 3:
                game.updatePosition(353, 471);
                break;
            case 4:
                game.updatePosition(395, 408);
                break;
            case 5:
                game.updatePosition(433, 471);
                break;
            case 6:
                game.updatePosition(475, 408);
                break;
            case 7:
                game.updatePosition(513, 471);
                break;
            case 8:
                game.updatePosition(555, 408);
                break;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < observers.size(); i++)
        {
            game.getS().getVehicles().add(
                    new Car(getClass().getResource(
                            "/speedrace/game/bluecar.png")));

            game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).setMass(0.9f);
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).setMaxSteering(500.0f);
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).updateVelocity(80.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        updatePosition(clientID, positions);

        game.setVisible(true);
        game.getS().requestFocusInWindow();
        sendCurrentCarPosition(game.getS().getVehicles().get(0).getPosition(),clientID);
    }

    public void updatePosition(int id, ArrayList<Point2D.Float> positions){
        if(id==1){
            for (int i = 1; i < game.getS().getVehicles().size(); i++)
            {
                game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).updatePosition(positions.get(i));              
            }

        }else if(id==2){
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(1).updatePosition(positions.get(0));              
            for (int i = 2; i < game.getS().getVehicles().size(); i++)
            {
                game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).updatePosition(positions.get(i));  
            }
        }else if(id==3){
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(1).updatePosition(positions.get(0));  
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(2).updatePosition(positions.get(1));
            for (int i = 3; i < game.getS().getVehicles().size(); i++)
            {
                game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).updatePosition(positions.get(i));  
            }
        }else if(id==4){
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(1).updatePosition(positions.get(0));  
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(2).updatePosition(positions.get(1));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(3).updatePosition(positions.get(2));
            for (int i = 4; i < game.getS().getVehicles().size(); i++)
            {
                game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).updatePosition(positions.get(i));  
            }
        }else if(id==5){
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(1).updatePosition(positions.get(0));  
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(2).updatePosition(positions.get(1));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(3).updatePosition(positions.get(2));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(4).updatePosition(positions.get(3));
            for (int i = 5; i < game.getS().getVehicles().size(); i++)
            {
                game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).updatePosition(positions.get(i));  
            }
        }else if(id==6){
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(1).updatePosition(positions.get(0));  
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(2).updatePosition(positions.get(1));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(3).updatePosition(positions.get(2));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(4).updatePosition(positions.get(3));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(5).updatePosition(positions.get(4));
            for (int i = 6; i < game.getS().getVehicles().size(); i++)
            {
                game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).updatePosition(positions.get(i));  
            }
        }else if(id==7){
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(1).updatePosition(positions.get(0));  
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(2).updatePosition(positions.get(1));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(3).updatePosition(positions.get(2));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(4).updatePosition(positions.get(3));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(5).updatePosition(positions.get(4));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(6).updatePosition(positions.get(5));
            for (int i = 7; i < game.getS().getVehicles().size(); i++)
            {
                game.getS().getVehicles().get(i).updatePosition(positions.get(i));  
            }
        }else if(id==8){
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(1).updatePosition(positions.get(0));  
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(2).updatePosition(positions.get(1));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(3).updatePosition(positions.get(2));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(4).updatePosition(positions.get(3));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(5).updatePosition(positions.get(4));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(6).updatePosition(positions.get(5));
            game.getS().getVehicles().get(7).updatePosition(positions.get(6));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateCarPosition(ArrayList<Point2D.Float> positions)
            throws RemoteException
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+"= ["+positions.get(i).x+", "+positions.get(i).y+"]");         
        }
        System.out.println("My clienID is: "+clientID+" my car size is: "+ game.getS().getVehicles().size());
        updatePosition(clientID, positions);

    }

    @Override
    public void sendCurrentCarPosition(final Point2D.Float position, final int clientID) throws RemoteException
    {

        class UpdateThread implements Runnable
        {
            boolean running = true;
            public void run()
            {
                while (running)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        System.out.println(clientID+" send  his position to the server: "+position.x+", "+position.y);
                        serverSet.sendCurrentCarPosition(position, clientID);
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    }

                    catch (RemoteException re)
                    {
                        re.printStackTrace();
                        view
                                .error("Trouble connecting to server. Please restart the server.");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        view
                                .error("Trouble connecting to server. Please restart the server.");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        final UpdateThread t = new UpdateThread();
        new Thread(t).start();
    }



}
```

Comment: This looks very much like another thread that I just saw. Your question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251760/strange-exception

Comment: *Exactly this line* appears 7 times in your code...

Comment: *What can we change*? - use local variables instead of those "chained" expressions. Your code is close to unreadable...

Comment: @Kaj - that was a different problem (was NPE, now it's an AIOOBE on the same line of code, NPE has been fixed obviously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for-loops you almost always start from 1. Is that correct?

To let us find the problem, you should post more code, I guess.

Comment: @Vladislav Bogdanov: You marked this as a correct answer. What was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Either `positions` has 0 elements or `game.getS().getVehicles()` has `<2` elements. Test for those conditions and act appropriately.

Comment: The size of positions is always 8 and game.getS().getVehicles()'s size is the number of connected observers. In our testing case it's always 2. So this IndexOutOfBounds Exception made no reason. And one more thing. The compiler drop this exception in client 1, but the line of code is limited to client2 by a if, else-if statement, and it shoudn't be visible for client 1. PLease help.